# how to create paginate for datagrid view

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I have a DataGrid in my wpf page. How can i add pagination to this datagrid ?.
I used LinqToSql class to get data from database.

I bind data to datagrid like follow

```
var supplier = (from p in cd.suppliers
                 select p).Take(10);
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = supplier;
```

this table columns are --> Sup_Id,Sup_Name,Phone_Num,Email,Description,Address

here is my xaml

```
<Grid Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top">



        <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" x:Uid="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                   AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,47,0,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding  Path=Sup_Id}" IsReadOnly="True" 
                                Header="Supplier ID" Width="150" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Sup_Name}" 

                                Header="Suppier Name" Width="200" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Phone_Num}" 
                                Header="Mobile" Width="190" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Email}" 

                                Header="Email" Width="230" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Address}" 

                                Header="Address" Width="250" />



            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Margin="464,500,464,-51" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Margin="4,0" Content="back" Click="back_click"/>
            <Button Margin="4,0" Content="next" Click="next_click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dataPager :

```
                            <datagrid>Your dataGrid</datagrid>
                            <sdk:DataPager Name="dataPager" 
                                           DisplayMode="FirstLastPreviousNext"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           PageSize="15"/>
```

PageSize is the number of line you want per Page.

And in the code behind :

```
               var supplier = (from p in cd.suppliers
             select p);
                MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = supplier; 
                dataPager.Source = supplier;
```

Here, you must load all datas you want. The dataPager will do the work.

If you call 30 lines, it will have 2 pages for example.

You can limit the number you take, but it is useless for the pagination.

**EDIT** : Misread your question : you are in WPF not Silverlight, try this link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f43b225-7a23-4f16-bff8-cdbb5864038b/wpf-datapager?forum=wpf

Comment: Ah, my bad, You are in WPF. I though you were in Silverlight. Take this link.

Comment: thanks for helping me.I solve my proble using http://www.nullskull.com/a/1368/wpf-datagrid-custom-paging-and-sorting.aspx link.